# form validation in material ui alongside Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm currently working on a register form using react, and using axios to connect with my Django Rest Framework API, but I got some issue with from validation, I look up many solutions but many of them use React class component, and those using react function component don't work with axios.

I could really use your help on any type of form validation that i could use, this is my current code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axiosInstance from '../../../network/axios';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
//Material-Ui 

import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';


function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    // backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(62deg, #bbbbbb 0%, #6b6868 100%)',
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    // background: 'linear-gradient(62deg, #bbbbbb 0%, #6b6868 100%)',
    background:'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(9,42,121,1) 0%, rgba(11,161,163,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 80%)',
    // background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
  },
}));


export default function SignUp() {
  //histoary to make a redirect to 
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const history = useHistory();
  const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
    email: '',
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    password1: '' ,
    password2: '' ,
  });
  
  const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateFormData({
      ...formData,
      // Trimming any whitespace
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    axiosInstance
        .post(`users/create/`, {
          email: formData.email,
          first_name: formData.first_name ,
          last_name: formData.last_name ,
          password1: formData.password1 ,
          password2: formData.password2 ,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          history.push('/welcome');
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
        });
  }

  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="first_name"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="first_name"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="last_name"
                label="Last Name"
                name="last_name"
                autoComplete="lname"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password1"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password1"
                autoComplete="current-password1"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password2"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password2"
                autoComplete="current-password2"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox value="allowExtraEmails" color="primary" />}
                label="I want to receive inspiration, marketing promotions and updates via email."
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button 
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick= {handleSubmit}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
        </form>
        <Grid container justify="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Button hcomponent={Link} to="/logins" variant="body2">
                Already have an account? Sign in
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik for form validation before submitting form.

Comment: Yes it what I end up working with at the end, it perfects !, I forgot replay earlier